# How to run stored procedure every second automatically (sql server 2014 Express)?

Tags: sql-server-express

I want to run stored procedure every second automatically.As I am using SQL Server 2014 **Express** edition so it is not possible to do the same with SQL Server Agent. Also, I don't have any third party tools to do so. I know it can be achieved by using Task Scheduler, sqlcmd utility or by using third-party tools but I don't know the exact way to do that.

I know this can be done and therefore I'm sure it's something I've missed but if anyone can share their experience of this I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough one. You're on the right track that you need an outside method to run the job, but I'd recommend writing one yourself to do it if you need the frequency every second (and also question if you *really* need it every second or not). A service or light application would be the best way to handle it.

I've written an article on setting up [Task Scheduler for automated jobs on SQL Server Express](http://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-replace-sql-agent/), but that has a limit of once/minute. You would use the `sqlcmd` utility in this case.

You can look at third party utilities like [JAMS Scheduler](http://www.jamsscheduler.com/), but their community edition is only free for a year.

That being said, I don't know of any quick-and-easy methods that satisfy your frequency requirements as stated.